# How to plot local date and time vs temperature from CSV file that uses UTC for date and time

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, utc

I have a CSV file where each row has date and time and temperature, where the date and time are UTC.

I can plot temperature as a function of time, but the X axis shows the UTC time.

What is the best way to generate a plot where the X axis shows my local time (which is currently Pacific Daylight Time)?

The current Python code is as follows, so currently I am just plotting temperature as a function of the UTC time and am not using date, which is in a separate column.

I have done some searching and reading, but so far have not found anything that directly addresses this problem.  I am a newbie in Pandas, so I am sure that a straightforward solution is out there somewhere.

`import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('LFEM_data-.csv',skiprows=1)
xvalues='Time'
yvalues = ['Temperature']
df.plot(x=xvalues, y=yvalues)
plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tz_convert` function on a `datetime` type `pandas` column to convert it to PDT.

```
import pandas as pd
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tdf['Time'])
df['Time_local'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_convert('PST8PDT')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think we are heading in the right direction, though I had to use tz_localize instead of tz_convert.  Also, the resulting graph looked very strange.  I see no way to include the graph here, but the graph was very distorted.  I will need to do more investigation.  Here is a link to the website where you can generate the CSV files: http://www-k12.atmos.washington.edu/k12/grayskies/nw_weather.html

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

`import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('LFEM_data-.csv',skiprows=1)
df['DateTime'] = df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
ts_utc = df['DateTime'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
df['DateTime_local'] = ts_utc.dt.tz_convert('America/Tijuana')
xvalues='DateTime_local'
yvalues = ['Temperature']
df.plot(x=xvalues, y=yvalues)
plt.show()`